# MVVM and (dynamically) filling a combobox from the value of another combobox

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a form with two ComboBoxes. One of them is being filled with objects coming from a collection in the ViewModel. When I select a value in this ComboBox, it then should fill the second ComboBox.

What I want to know is what the best way is to go about filling the second ComboBox. I think having yet another collection with the details of the selected value of the first ComboBox in the ViewModel might be a bit wasteful. I think the best way might be to hit the database with the selected value, collecting the corresponding details, and then send them back. How I *think* this would work is to have the details ComboBox have a binding with the 'master' ComboBox so it can get the selected value. Then ideally, the details ComboBox would then somehow get the values from the database.

Problem is that I just don't know how to implement this with MVVM, and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `OnPropertyChanged` of the details collection once the selected item changes.

You can pre-populate a background dictionary whose key is the possible master items and whose values are a list of detail list.

Note for the below to work you `ViewModel` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

e.g.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public IEnumerable<MasterOption> MasterList {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<DetailOption> DetailList {get;set;}
  Dictionary<MasterOption,List<DetailOption>> DetailLookup;
  MasterOption _SelectedMasterOption;
  public MasterOption SelectedMasterOption
  { 
    get { return _SelectedMasterOption;}
    set 
    { 
      _SelectedMasterOption = value; 
      LoadDetailsList(); 
      OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMasterOption"); 
     }

  void LoadDetailsList()
  {
    InitDictionary();
    if (DetailLookup.ContainsKey(SelectedMasterOption))
      DetailList = DetailLookup[SelectedMasterOption];
    else
      DetailList = null;

    OnPropertyChanged("DetailList");
  }  
  void InitDictionary()
  {
    if (DetailLookup == null)
    {
      //Grab fill the lookup dictionary with information
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to try this one out right now, but I have a couple of questions. I see in the code that you call `LoadDetailsList()`, but without handing it something so it can determine which details to grab. 2. what exactly do you mean with _Just call OnPropertyChanged of the details collection once the selected item changes._? And the `Dictionary` will then be something like `Dictionary<MasterOption, DetailOption>`.

Comment: I get it, I'm sorry - In the `LoadDetailsList` you use the `_SelectedMasterOption`. My other question still stands though ;-)

Comment: I modified the code above, hope that helps. The way I did it isn't the only way, it's just A way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your ViewModel that gets the data for the second combobox and update with BindingExpression in your codebehind.

```
private void FirstComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        _viewModel.SelectionChange();
        BindingExpression bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(SecondComboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty);
        bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
    }
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but I'm trying to really not put anything in my code behind :-)